# Residually nilpotent groups with no infinite subgroup that is nilpotent

Tags: geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Is there an example of an infinite, residually nilpotent, torsion group that does not contain an infinite abelian subgroup.

I am looking for particular example or a reasoning why such a group cannot exist.

The motivation is the following: I am trying to construct a relatively one-ended relatively hyperbolic group whose peripheral subgroups are residually nilpotent but not nilpotent and which does not admit parabolic splitting.

So I begin by constructing a one-ended relatively hyperbolic group $(G, \mathbb{P})$ with whose peripheral subgroups are residually nilpotent but not nilpotent (construction is due to Cordes and Hume). Now use an accessibility theorem due to Bowditch and consider the peripheral splitting of $(G, \mathbb{P})$. A component $H$ of this splitting is again relatively hyperbolic with respect to the infinite subgroups of the form $Q = H \cap P$ where $P \in \mathbb{P}$. Moreover $(H, \mathbb{Q})$ is relatively one-ended and does not admit further parabolic splitting (due to Bowditch's theorem). I need the the members of $\mathbb{Q}$ to be residually nilpotent and not nilpotent to claim that $(H, \mathbb{Q})$ is the desired example. Hence I need each infinite $H \cap P$ to be residually nilpotent and not nilpotent.

Comment: You need to remove "proper" from the question. Otherwise, the Prüfer group (union of $\mathbf{Z}/p^n\mathbf{Z}$ over $n$) is a trivial counterexample. [Usually such an adjective avoids trivial counterexamples, but here it adds one...] Also "virtually" is useless in the question: once you have an infinite virtually nilpotent subgroup, you clearly also have an infinite nilpotent one.

Comment: Already the question (once corrected) is not obvious because the group has to be torsion (no infinite cyclic subgroup), and not locally finite (because an infinite locally finite group has an infinite abelian subgroup). An infinite nilpotent group actually always contains an infinite abelian group, so you can change "nilpotent" to abelian in any case.

Comment: Also I'm unsure what you mean by growth, for a subgroup that is not finitely generated (and thus don't really follow the motivation of the question).

Comment: I have edited the question and given more context. It seems from your comments that the group I looking for is an infinite residually nilpotent torsion group that does not contain an infinite abelian subgroup?

Comment: This is correct (but this is not what you wrote in your edit: "virtually free" is irrelevant and "infinite" is missing)

Comment: I have made another edit. Is there a known group of this description?

Comment: I guess it's unknown. If there is an example, then there is a finitely generated one. Also, since it's torsion and residually nilpotent, it's a (necessarily finite) direct sum of $p$-groups when $p$ ranges over primes, and hence we can pick one factor to suppose that it's a $p$-group for some prime $p$.